# Why does one of these produce an error and the other does not?

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to run a simple python script to populate my Teams database for my django project under the teams app. The script is reading a list, I have included it below under the error on things I've tried and the results I expected. I understand it has something to do with the *"python needing to setup DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE".*

```py
(.venv) root@firstfiverugbycloud:/home/django/firstfiverugby# python populate_teams.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/firstfiverugby/populate_teams.py", line 2, in <module>
    from teams.models import Team, League
  File "/home/django/firstfiverugby/teams/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class League(models.Model):
  File "/home/django/firstfiverugby/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/django/firstfiverugby/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/django/firstfiverugby/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/django/firstfiverugby/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/django/firstfiverugby/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
(.venv) root@firstfiverugbycloud:/home/django/firstfiverugby# python manage.py shell < populate_teams.py
(.venv) root@firstfiverugbycloud:/home/django/firstfiverugby#
```

I am just trying to run a script to populate my database with test teams for a website I am building. The script just imports the models from my django app.

```py
# Import the Team model from your Django app
from teams.models import Team, League

# Create teams for each city with historical descriptions and placeholders
# Sample data for teams
teams_data = [
    {
        'name': 'White Plains',
        'crest': 'white_plains_crest.jpg',
        'banner_image': 'white_plains_banner.jpg',
        'description': 'White Plains Rugby Team',
        'founded_in': 1971,
        'division': 'Local',
        'rank': 'Top 10',
        'state': 'New York',
        'city': 'White Plains',
        'league': None,  # Set to the appropriate league instance if needed
    },.....

] # end of list

# Create teams in the database
    for data in teams_data:
      Team.objects.create(**data)
```

Why does this work? I tried it at the end.

```py
(.venv) root@firstfiverugbycloud:/home/django/firstfiverugby# python manage.py shell < populate_teams.py
```

Comment: Because `manage.py shell` sets up a bunch of things for you, then runs your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`manage.py` loads the Django settings for you:

```py
# manage.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MyProject.settings")
    ...
```

If you want to work with Django stuff (like accessing models) in a standalone script, you have to configure the settings yourself: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage